# custom day and month as the output of program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have question about time. How to custom output time?

```
'Sat Dec 03 08:38:34 2016'
```

But I want to do something like this for example, 
Sat will become Sabtu, Dec become Desember or more like this

```
Sabtu, 03 Desember 2016, jam 08:34:34
```

Comment: The simplest way would be just replace the strings with what you want, a bit like `d = 'Sat Dec 06'`, `d = d.replace('Sat', 'Sabtu')`, `d = d.replace('Dec', 'Desember')`, etc, you'd do it for each day and month.

Comment: @Peter Sure, that works for this one example. What about all other months and days?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985505/locale-date-formatting-in-python

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593661/how-do-i-strftime-a-date-object-in-a-different-locale#24070673

Comment: @Peter, thanks, but how about the another day ??

Comment: I just meant repeat what I did for every day/month, such as `d = d.replace('Mon', 'day1')`, `d = d.replace('Tue', 'day2')`, `d = d.replace('Jan', 'month1'), `d = d.replace('Feb', 'month2')`, etc :P    I thought you were making up a language though to be fair, though google translate says that's indonesian, so follow those links above if you are