# Robot Framework How to get different timezone and locale for different country?

Tags: python, robotframework

In robot framework, the current supported keyword to get timezone is:

```
${month}  Get Current Date  result_format=%B%Y
```

which will return: July 2017

The question is how to get current date from other country and locale?
as example in Vietnam should return: `Tháng Bảy 2017`
and Thailand should return : `กรกฎาคม พ.ศ. 2560`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, python doesn't have good built-in support for formatting dates in locales other than the current one. You can temporarily switch locales, but that's not a great solution.

You can use the the [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/) package to format the dates, though it doesn't provide precisely the same value you expect -- the case is slightly different.

For example, you could create a keyword that dates a month, year, and locale, and returns the formatted version.

First, create a python file named `CustomKeywords.py` with the following contents:

```
# CustomKeywords.py
import datetime
from babel.dates import format_date

class CustomKeywords:
    def get_date_for_locale(self, locale, year, month=1, day=1):
        d = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
        return format_date(d, "MMMM Y", locale=locale)
```

Next, import this library into your test case and then call `get date for locale` to get the date for a given locale:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  CustomKeywords.py

*** Test Case ***
Vietnamese
    ${date}=  get date for locale  vi_VN  2017  7
    Should be equal  ${date}  tháng bảy 2017

Thailand
    ${date}=  get date for locale  th_TH  2017  7
    Should be equal  ${date}  กรกฎาคม 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Robot Framework Datetime library the concept of changing the TimeZone is not present. The Robot Framework [Custom Timestamp](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Custom%20timestamp) functions rely on the underlying Python [datatime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) function. This function uses the python Locale for it's formatting.

As this has now become a more general Python problem, I've searched SO and found this particular [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18594128/6152737) to fulfill the criteria to create a custom Python Keyword for Robot Framework that would allow changing the Locale and thus determine the output.