# Locale sensitive date time parsing in Python

Tags: python

I need to parse a date time in a non-English language, on a machine running with an en-us locale. The easy solution to this problem would be to do `setlocale` and then proceed to `strptime`.

The problem is that if you `setlocale`, it gets set program-wide. However, due to the nature of my program, many threads are running and run locale sensitive processes.

This means `setlocale` is not an option, because it messes with it globally. How can I `strptime` with a different locale?

Comment: Here's a thread-safe way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593661/how-do-i-strftime-a-date-object-in-a-different-locale

Comment: Using a lock seems like overkill for something that should be solvable without it

Comment: an alternative is to use another library like Babel: http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/dates.html

Comment: Babel doesn't seem to have the feature that I need (parse with formatting)