# Parsing date with german month names

Tags: python, date, format, translation

I try to read a csv-file with german month days like 'Mai' etc.
When I try: `datetime.date.strptime('Mai 2009','%B %Y'))` it results in a

```
ValueError: time data 'Mai 2009' does not match format '%B %Y'
```

The defaultlocale ist 'de_DE'

Is there an easy solution for translation ?

Comment: take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593661/how-do-i-strftime-a-date-object-in-a-different-locale/24070673)

Comment: You need to use at least `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '')` to make the locale effective. See also the respective section from Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats)