# Datetime string with whitespace, local date

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

I am trying to convert a datetime string (German) that comes from MS Project Excel Export.

02 Februar 2022 17:00

I read it from a Excel-Export of MS Project in to a pandas dataframe.

When converting it with

```
to_datetime(df["Anfang"], format= '%d %B %Y %H:%M').dt.date
```

but get the error

```
ValueError: time data '07 Januar 2019 07:00' does not match format '%d %B %Y %H:%M' (match)
```

from https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

```
%B   Month as locale’s full name.   September
```

What I am doing wrong here?
Do I have to check some local settings?
I am using German(Swiss)

```
import locale
locale.getdefaultlocale()
('de_CH', 'cp1252')
```

df in:

```
0       10 April 2019 08:00
1      07 Januar 2019 07:00
2      07 Januar 2019 07:00
3      07 Januar 2019 07:00
4     09 Oktober 2019 17:00
5    04 Dezember 2020 17:00
Name: Anfang, dtype: object
```

df out (wanted):

```
0       10-04-2019
1       07-01-2019
.
.
```

**EDIT:**
I changed my locale to ('de_DE', 'cp1252'), but I get the same error.

**SOLVED:**
By using matJ's answer, I got the error that "Die 15.06.21" was not matching the format, which led me to investigate the data. There I found two different date  formats (Thanks, Microsoft!). After cleaning, the above code worked well!!!
So the error message of `to_datetime` wasn't precise as `datetime.strptime`.

Thanks for helping.

Johannes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I strftime a date object in a different locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593661/how-do-i-strftime-a-date-object-in-a-different-locale)

Comment: @LinSel: I checked that, but I don't want to change the locale. I could not find information about if the `de_CH` locale is recognized by `strftime`. If it isn't, I will use dateparser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change the locale in a different way. Then your code should work.

The following works for me:

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime 

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')  # changing locale to german 
datetime.strptime('07 Januar 2019 07:00', '%d %B %Y %H:%M')  # returns a datetime obj which you can format as you like
```

Let me know if that works for you as well.

Comment: Your aproach led me to the solution, actualy the problem. When using it with `df_tp_cm["Anfang"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%d %B %Y %H:%M'))` I got the error about a value, that was'nt matching (weird MS Project export, two different formats for date...). When cleaning this, my initial aproach worked well also! But there I got the wrong error value that didn't match (Die 15.06.21) . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is use [`dateparser`](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) module:

```
import dateparser

df['Anfang'] = df['Anfang'].apply(dateparser.parse)
print (df)
               Anfang
0 2019-04-10 08:00:00
1 2019-01-07 07:00:00
2 2019-01-07 07:00:00
3 2019-01-07 07:00:00
4 2019-10-09 17:00:00
5 2020-12-04 17:00:00
```

---

```
import dateparser

df['Anfang'] = df['Anfang'].apply(dateparser.parse).dt.date
print (df)
       Anfang
0  2019-04-10
1  2019-01-07
2  2019-01-07
3  2019-01-07
4  2019-10-09
5  2020-12-04
```

Comment: This works great. But would be nice to work with `pandas` only.

Comment: @nanuuq - I agree, but I think not possible (from my informtion, maybe I am wrong)